# How to reduce height of one row in longtable?

Tags: longtable

I am preparing a document with a quite special format: the first row in a long table should be written with `\scriptsize` font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{
 \centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{
 \centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|}
 \hline   
 {\bf\scriptsize 1} & {\bf\scriptsize 2} &
 {\bf\scriptsize 3} & {\bf\scriptsize 4} &
 {\bf\scriptsize 5}
 \\  \hline 
 \endfirsthead
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I would like to reduce height of the first row. The lower vertical space can be reduced by replacing `\\` with `\\[-0.3em]` after the first row. But what to do with the upper space? I would be appreciate for any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were no vertical rules you could do

```
\hline
\noalign{\vskip-3pt}
```

(and unrelated, but  use   `\bfseries\scriptpsize 3 &` not `{\bf\scriptsize 3} &` )

---

But as there are you could do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\def\mystrut{\vrule height 8pt depth 2pt width 0pt\kern4\arrayrulewidth}
 \begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{
 \centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{
 \centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}|}
 \hline   
\omit\vrule \scriptsize\bfseries\mystrut\hfill 1 \hfill\vrule&
\omit       \scriptsize\bfseries\mystrut\hfill 2 \hfill\vrule&
\omit       \scriptsize\bfseries\mystrut\hfill 3 \hfill\vrule&
\omit       \scriptsize\bfseries\mystrut\hfill 4 \hfill\vrule&
\omit       \scriptsize\bfseries\mystrut\hfill 5 \hfill\vrule\\
  \hline 
 \endfirsthead
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
 \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that this reduces the upper space but also results in vertical lines above the table. How to remove them?

Comment: @Andrew Avoid vertical rules: they are *evil*. ;-)

Comment: These vertical lines are more than evil: they are suggested by some bureaucratic rules:)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Now I will try to apply it for my document.

Answer (score -1):

Use `\vspace(-0.3in)` with a negative value.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please elaborate on this (and use correct syntax please). Where should the OP put it f.i.?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".